# What is the size of this struct?

Tags: c

```
 typedef struct {
 char valid;
 char tag;
 char block[4];
} line;
```

I believe it's 6, because `block[]` is 4, and each char is 1 byte. This is on an x86 machine. Is there an offset between `valid` and `tag`? Should it be 8?

Comment: `printf("%zu", sizeof line);` might tell you?

Comment: It is compiler, system/alignment dependent. How the compiler or system handles padding will cause the count to vary from compiler-to-compiler, etc.

Comment: The only limitation imposed by the C specification is that there can be no padding before `valid`. The compiler can put as much padding as it wants between the members, and at the end of the struct.

Comment: yeah I should just test it with that. I have to work in assembly for an assignment and I'm having trouble accessing the struct. should probably have asked a better question

Comment: And if you need to know the offsets of the various members of the struct (for example, there might be padding between `tag` and `block`) you can use the `offsetof` macro. Note that if you want there to be no padding, compilers nearly always provide options, pragmas, or keyword extensions to allow you to control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 6. Simple call to sizeof will confirm this.
Is this the question or is there any other question related to padding of structures?

Answer (score 4):

if you want the size of a struct use the `sizeof` operator.

e.g.

```
size_t struct_size = sizeof(line);
```

it returns the size of the struct in bytes. Note that sizeof(char) == 1 always, so technically byte does not always mean 8 bits.

From [C:TCN, "Page 348" at the bottom of the page](https://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html) :-

> It is in theory possible for a machine to have char be larger than 8
>   bits, though it's not very common for hosted environments (basically,
>   desktop computers and the like -- the only environments required to
>   even have the  functions to begin with).
>
> On such a machine,
>   contrary to many people's expectations, ***sizeof(char) is still 1***; what
>   changes is the value **CHAR_BIT**. The relevance of this is that, on such
>   a machine, it is possible for int to still have its required range,
>   but to be the same size as a char.
>
> Thus, on such a machine, there
>   might exist at least one value of unsigned char such that, converted
>   to int, it was a negative value, and compared equal to EOF. However,
>   to the best of my knowledge, all such systems that have provided the
>   getchar() function and related functions have ensured that, in fact,
>   the EOF value is distinct from any value which can actually be read
>   from a file. For instance, char could be a 32-bit type, but you would
>   still only see values 0-255 when reading "characters" from a file.

From WG14 n1256 - section 6.5.3.4:

> The sizeof operator yields the size **(in bytes)** of its operand ... When applied to an operand that has type , unsigned char, or signed char,
>   (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

Comment: *...technically byte does not always mean 8 bits.* - May I know how? It is unclear from your answer.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful C does not mandate that a char is 8 bits and sizeof(char) == 1. If a char is 32 bits for some reason, then 32 bits is a byte. I've seen the term byte usually used as the smallest unit of information; I don't think it is required to be 8 bits. see the page 348 section of this (near the bottom): https://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html

Comment: I am making a necessary edit in our answer to highlight those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sizeof. Here's a program to tell you the size of line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char valid;
    char tag;
    char block[4];
} line;

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(line));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sizeof` function to get the used memory to alloc that struct.

```
printf("%i" , sizeof(line));
```